# WCF Service not returning data

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a simple WCF project that accepts XML as a string and parses the XML to build a search object.  The search object then is used to make calls to a referenced project that calls a SQL stored procedure.  The results are then put into a class and the class is Serialized as XML and returned as a string by the WCF service.  I was able to debug the WCF service by starting it and adding it as a web reference by another project.  In Debug mode it returns the XML with 14 records.  I then published the WCF service to an IIS site and it returns XML but with no records.  The search object is there since it is just parsed but the return from the referenced code has 0 records.

Sample code is below.  All seems to execute but the PerformSearch code isn't returning results.

Any ideas??

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>


public class NCSupplierService : INCSupplierService
{

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }

    public string ProcessOrder(string value)
    {

        try
        {
            XmlDocument oDoc = new XmlDocument();
            oDoc.LoadXml(value);

            string Login = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("NCCriminal/login/user").InnerText.Trim();
            string Password = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("NCCriminal/login/password").InnerText.Trim();

            XmlNode OrderFields = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("NCCriminal/product/Statewide/order");

            int SolutionID = Int32.Parse(oDoc.SelectSingleNode("NCCriminal").Attributes["referenceKey"].Value);
            string FirstName = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("firstName").InnerText.Trim();
            string MiddleName = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("middleName").InnerText.Trim();
            string LastName = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("lastName").InnerText.Trim();
            int dobmonth = Int32.Parse(OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("DOB/month").InnerText.Trim());
            int dobday = Int32.Parse(OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("DOB/day").InnerText.Trim());
            int dobyear = Int32.Parse(OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("DOB/year").InnerText.Trim());
            string SSN = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("SSN").InnerText.Trim();
            string Gender = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("Gender").InnerText.Trim();
            string Race = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("Race").InnerText.Trim();
            string License = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("DriversLicense/license").InnerText.Trim();
            string LicenseState = OrderFields.SelectSingleNode("DriversLicense/state").InnerText.Trim();
            bool LimitToToDay = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("NCCriminal/product/Statewide/options/LimitToToday").InnerText.Trim() == "NO" ? false : true;


            string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            NCSearchTerms SearchTerms = new NCSearchTerms(LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, Gender, Race, new DateTime(dobyear, dobmonth, dobday).ToShortDateString(), SSN, new Datastructure.BaseClasses.DriversLicenseType(SolutionID, License, LicenseState));
            NCSearch search = new NCSearch(SearchTerms, SolutionID);
            if(!search.PerformSearch(ref search, SolutionID, LimitToToDay, out ErrorMessage))
                throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
                throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);

            NCCriminalResponse response = new NCCriminalResponse();
            response.SolutionID = SolutionID;
            response.SearchTerms = SearchTerms;
            response.RecordCount = search.SearchResults.SearchResults.Count();
            response.DemographicCaseRecords = search.SearchResults.SearchResults;


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(SerializeXML.SerializeObject(response));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>");
            sb.Append("<NCCriminalResponse xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">");
            sb.Append("<ProcessingError>");
            sb.Append("<ErrorMessage>");
            sb.Append(Ex.Message);
            sb.Append("</ErrorMessage>");
            sb.Append("</ProcessingError>");
            sb.Append("</NCCriminalResponse>");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class NCCriminalResponse
{
    public int SolutionID;
    public NCSearchTerms SearchTerms;
    public int RecordCount = 0;
    public List<DemographicCase> DemographicCaseRecords = new List<DemographicCase>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [ServiceContract] attribute to **INCSupplierService** interface and add [OperationContract] attribute to its

```
string ProcessOrder(string value);
```

property.

Add [DataContract] attribute to **NCCriminalResponse** and add [DataMember] attribute to its public properties.